# Marathon GUI testing how to select cell from Jtable which doent has column name

Tags: java, python-2.7, marathontesting

I am trying to automate my java application using marathon, currently stuck in a point to select cell from a table, but column does not have index name.
Actually it works with the command which has column index name like below:

```
select('table_name', 'rows:[0],columns:[column_index_name]')
```

I have tried below command:

```
select('table_name','rows:[0],columns:[2]')
```

and

```
select('table_name', [{ 'row': 0, 'columnIndex': 2 }])
```

None of this is working, can anybody please help me?

I am using python as scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

A bug in Marathon is not allowing you to use columnIndex :(

Meanwhile, you can try using click as follows:

`click('table_name', '{0,2}')`

Note the absence of spaces in second parameter. Having spaces causes a problem (another bug).

Comment: yes...this option is working fine for selecting the cells from table..thanks.